# JQuery Keydown event is not working in IE 11

Tags: jquery, keydown, keycode

I created Tab UI. When I press next/previous arrow key, next/previous tab must be focused.

It works in Chrome, but not working in IE 11. the problem is, next/previous tab is not focused.

I tried many codes that `event = event || window.event;`, `event.preventDefault()`, etc...

Thank you for run code snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".tabmenu li").on("mousedown focusin keydown", function(e){

        var keycode = e.keyCode || e.which;

        $(".tabmenu li").removeAttr("class tabindex");
        $(this).addClass("on").attr("tabindex", "0").focus();

        switch(keycode){
            case 37:
                $(this).prev().addClass("on").attr("tabindex", "0").focus();
                break;

            case 39:
                $(this).next().addClass("on").attr("tabindex", "0").focus();
                break;
            }
    });
});
```

```css
.tabmenu:after {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    content: ""
}

.tabmenu li {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    margin: -1px 0 0 -1px;
    padding: 13px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ce5050;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    cursor: pointer;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.tabmenu li.on,
.tabmenu li:hover {
    background-color: #fddbdb;
    font-weight: 700
}
```

```html
<ul class="tabmenu">
    <li tabindex="0" class="on">tab1</li>
    <li>tab2</li>
    <li>tab3</li>
</ul>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key

Comment: Also `$(".tabmenu li").on("mousedown focusin keydown", function(e){

        var keycode = e.keyCode || e.which;` <<< will not exist on mousedown and focusin